# Отправка всем устройствам push firebase

Tags: android, firebase, push

Здравствуйте!Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с проблемой!С сервера на одно устройство разобрался как отправлять а вот сразу всем телефонам не могу понять как!

```
define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'AAAAhvIpZGfE:APA91b...-...RCtcNOdZv-BsIWa' );
$registrationIds = 'euJDiXsaO.--.YeqJE0BxsUSH0R';
$msg = array
(
'message'   => 'here is a message. message',
'title'   => 'This is a title. title',
'subtitle'  => 'This is a subtitle. subtitle',
'tickerText'  => 'Ticker text here...Ticker text here...Ticker text here',
'vibrate' => 1,
'sound'   => 1,
'largeIcon' => 'large_icon',
'smallIcon' => 'small_icon'
);
$fields = array
(

'registration_ids'  => array($registrationIds),
'data'      => $msg
);

$headers = array
(
'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
'Content-Type: application/json'
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
$result = curl_exec($ch );
curl_close( $ch );
echo $result;
```

Comment: Вам прямо вообще всем надо девайсам? Или большому кол-ву девайсов с заранее известными ID?

Comment: Всем!В firebase есть выбор "сегмент пользователей" и он рассылает всем устройствам!

Comment: Я не уверен, но предполагаю, что они у себя используют в тихую `topics`. По крайней мере я недавно доку читал и только такой способ нашёл. Т.е. вам надо всех юзеров подписать на созданный вами топик на их девайсах, после чего слать пуши на этот топик

Comment: @Timon Вы же можете отправить на один `registration_id`. Теперь у вас есть массив этих `id`. Тогда, просто, пробегите циклом по массиву и отправьте сообщение каждому `registration_id`. Обычно так и делают, т.к. можно по ответу гугла проверить валиден ли токен и удалить его из базы, если он не валиден (изменился, к примеру).

Comment: Спасибо большое